# Plotting VIIRS against Longitude in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am having issues plotting average radiance from VIIRS dataset against longitude in the h-Axis. I have this code but I am getting an error message. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
// Load VIIRS  - to be summarized by longitude bins.
var viirs = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG")
  .select('avg_rad').first();

// Load lat/lon image - select the longitude band.
var latLon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');

// Make a list of longitude bin start values.
var step = 5; // longitude step
var lonStarts = ee.List.sequence(-90, 90-step, step);

// Map of the longitude list - get the mean radiance value for pixels in given
// longitude bin. Returns a list of features.
var lonStatList = lonStarts.map(function(lon) {
  var startLon = ee.Number(lon);
  var endLon = startLon.add(step);
  var targetPixels = latLon.gte(startLon).and(latLon.lt(endLon));
  var stat = viirs.updateMask(targetPixels).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    // Set geometry as needed - global in this case
    geometry: ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-179.99, -89.99, 179.99, 89.99),
    scale: 10000, // Change scale as needed
    bestEffort: true});
  return ee.Feature(viirs.geometry(), stat).set('lon', lon);
});

// Convert feature list to feature collection.
var lonStatsCol = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(lonStatList));

// Chart the results.
var chart =
  ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(lonStatsCol, 'lon', 'avg_rad')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Average Radiance by Longitude',
      hAxis: {title: 'Longitude'},
      vAxis: {title: 'nanoWatts/cm2/sr'}
    });
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about the geometry argument in the `reduceRegion` function was not working with that particular VIIRS dataset (works okay with the vegetation index product - possibly a bug or something about the dataset's projection or bounds). I modified the reduction so that the geometry argument is updated according to the longitude bin, which works.

```js
// Load VIIRS  - to be summarized by longitude bins.
var viirs = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG")
  .select('avg_rad').first();

// Load lat/lon image - select the longitude band.
var lonImg = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');

// Make a list of longitude bin start values.
var step = 5; // longitude step
var lonStarts = ee.List.sequence(-180, 180-step, step);

// Map over the longitude list - get the mean radiance value for pixels in given
// longitude bin by adjusting the reduction geometry. Returns a list of features.
var lonStatList = lonStarts.map(function(lon) {
  var startLon = ee.Number(lon);
  var endLon = startLon.add(step);
  var stat = viirs.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ee.Geometry.Rectangle(startLon, -90, endLon, 90),
    scale: 10000, // Change scale as needed
    bestEffort: true});
  return ee.Feature(viirs.geometry(), stat).set('lon', lon);
});

// Convert feature list into feature collection.
var lonStatsCol = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(lonStatList));

// Chart the results.
var chart =
  ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(lonStatsCol, 'lon', 'avg_rad')
    .setSeriesNames(['Average radiance'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Average Radiance by Longitude',
      hAxis: {title: 'Longitude'},
      vAxis: {title: 'nanoWatts/cm2/sr'}
    });
print(chart);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/76699c47f0521ad5888fecccf230c81d)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!